# Python change column name when it contains ('cost','Jan')

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to change a column name from ('cost','Jan') to just Jan however when I try

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'('cost',''Jan')' :'Jan"})
```

I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax from the , between ('cost',''Jan')

Sorry I cant do screen prints as the code is on another machine

Comment: Your quotation marks are all over the place, is this how it is in your code?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your problem? Also, remember to format your code properly! [This post will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Your code causes syntax error because you're using quotation inside a string which itself is created by quotation. So the parser can't parse it in the format you intended. If you create your string with double quotation it would probably work (if there is nothing wrong with other parts).

So you should try this:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={"('cost','Jan')" :"Jan"})
```

And if you want to insist on using single quotation you can use back slash to tell the parser to escape that quotation.

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'(\'cost\',\'Jan\')' :'Jan'})
```